# How to add x axis as datetime label in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I implemented line chart (MPAndroidChart library) for temperature report in my project.In X axis datetime should be plotted and Y axis temperature should be plotted.

I just added datetime as string in X axis label but it's collapsed. So please anyone guide me.

Comment: I have implement same which you want can you, please
Try [This.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40806503/1343788)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MPAndroidChart x-axis date/time label formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803233/mpandroidchart-x-axis-date-time-label-formatting)

Answer (score 6):

Using version 3.0+ of the MPAndroidChart:

Set formatter to the x axis (created below):

```
// Formatter to adjust epoch time to readable date
lineChart.xAxis.setValueFormatter(new LineChartXAxisValueFormatter());
```

Create a new class LineChartXAxisValueFormatter:

```
public class LineChartXAxisValueFormatter extends IndexAxisValueFormatter {

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value) {

        // Convert float value to date string
        // Convert from seconds back to milliseconds to format time  to show to the user
        long emissionsMilliSince1970Time = ((long) value) * 1000;

        // Show time in local version
        Date timeMilliseconds = new Date(emissionsMilliSince1970Time);
        DateFormat dateTimeFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, Locale.getDefault());

        return dateTimeFormat.format(timeMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

When the entries are added to the `chartDataArray` they are added in seconds, not milliseconds, to avoid potential precision issues with inputting as a float (i.e. milliseconds divided by 1000).

```
chartDataArray.add(new Entry(secondsSince1970Float, yValueFloat));
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Can you please explain how to add values  in this
chartDataArray.add(new Entry(secondsSince1970Float, yValueFloat));

Comment: This is done in a "for in" loop iterating through a map of secondsSince1970Float and yValueFloat data to feed into the chart.

Comment: yes got your point thanks

Comment: this doesn't work, I use `System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000f` always gives me the same value :(

Comment: @Sepultura, yes that will always give you current time. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Ben what I mean is, if I use System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000f and cast it to a float value, the float value is always the same, it doesn't change over time - perhabs can you give me an example how?

Comment: plus I can't cast it the float value to a long in the formatter, converting to float loses too many information

Comment: I tested it again, seems like this only works down to minute resolution, I would need it in seconds however

Answer (score 5):

Try the following.

To set the X Axis

```java
 XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(new MyXAxisValueFormatter());
        xAxis.setLabelsToSkip(0);
```

Create a new class `MyXAxisValueFormatter` implement `XAxisValueFormatter`

```java
public class MyXAxisValueFormatter implements XAxisValueFormatter {

@Override
public String getXValue(String dateInMillisecons, int index, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
    try {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM");
        return sdf.format(new Date(Long.parseLong(dateInMillisecons)));

    } catch (Exception e) {

        return  dateInMillisecons;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi for xaxis i added below can you please check whether it's correct or wrong ?
 ArrayList<String> xAxisValues = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < chartList.size(); i++) {
                xAxisValues.add(Utils.parseDateForChart(chartList.get(i).getDateTime()));
            }

Comment: Yes date is displayed. But the date is too long.

Comment: Yes How to avoid collapse ?

Comment: Add this to your chart 

mChart.setDragEnabled(true);
mChart.setPinchZoom(true);
mChart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(true);
mChart.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
mChart.getViewPortHandler().setMaximumScaleX(5f);
mChart.getViewPortHandler().setMaximumScaleY(5f);

Comment: I had implement same thing which you want. can you please, try This. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40806503/1343788

Comment: @ShanmugapriyanM: have you check, its working or not ?

Comment: @MehulKabaria I checked your response but I can't make it work because I can't figure out `BinSensorData` and `SensorInterval.Interval`, if you could provide the code or an explanation, it would be appreciated.

Comment: XAxisValueFormatter doesn't exist anymore, only ValueFormatter which only has a float value, which is too small do save a timestamp :(

Answer (score 2):

Further from @Ben's answer, if you are creating BarChart, and the time span of the bar is like an hour or a day, and you are supplying with millisecond or second data, you will end up getting the bars too thin to be visible.  This is a bug posted in 2017 (https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/2892) and remains unresolved to date unfortunately.

A workaround was proposed and it is to convert the millisecond values into your time span of the bar before setting then into BarEntry.  My time span is a day, so
I have the formatter as:

```
    static class BarChartXAxisValueFormatter extends IndexAxisValueFormatter {

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value) {

        // Convert float value to date string
        // Convert from days back to milliseconds to format time  to show to the user
        long emissionsMilliSince1970Time = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis((long)value);
        // Show time in local version
        Date timeMilliseconds = new Date(emissionsMilliSince1970Time);
        SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd");

        return dateTimeFormat.format(timeMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

And I set the X axis with:

```
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new BarChartXAxisValueFormatter());
```

Then when setting the data to the bar, I have

`new BarEntry(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays((long)valX), valY)`.

Answer (score 0):

If it still actually...

```
class DateAxisValueFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {
  private String[] mValues;

  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.hh");

  public DateAxisValueFormatter(String[] values) {
      this.mValues = values; }


   @Override
   public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        // "value" represents the position of the label on the axis (x or y)
        return mValues[(int) value];
      }
    }
```

- And your must  on Create put `String[]` values `(public DateAxisValueFormatter(String[] values) )` where each value is a DateString.
  Data series Entries for X (new Entry(forX,forY)) must be a `flat array = 0,1,2,3,4`
- Sorry, my poor English, I am from Russia.  From 1988 main chief of RealTime  Control System Developer Company for Hydro Power Plants (www.asu-epro.ru).
  Borodatov Michael miclosoft@mail.ru