# MPAndroidChart: Justifiy grid and labels to midnight (00:00) on date formatting

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, linechart

**Problem:**

MPAndroidChart calculates grid and label position nicely for decimal values but not so for a date/time axis.

I would like to have label positions justified to exactly midnight eg. with a x-axis range of 4 days on:

```
[26.1-00h, 27.1-00h, 28.1-00h,29.1-00h, 30.1-00h]
```

Or if the range is eg. only 2 days:

```
[26.1-00h, 26.1-12h, 27.1-00h, 27.1-12h,28.1-00h]
```

etc.

**What I tried:**

1. Adapting the solution of [MPAndroidChart x-axis date/time label formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803233/mpandroidchart-x-axis-date-time-label-formatting) but it didn't work for recent release 3.1.0 of MPAndroidChart.
2. Correcting the Chart min and max by using *setAxisMinimum()*  and *setAxisMaximum()* to midnight timestamps.
3. Playing with different value scaling.
4. Setting the granularity with *setGranularity()* to a whole day, but then datapoints snaps away from its original to ganularity positions.

The calculation of the grid origin and spacing seems to be done in *computeAxisValues()* of class *AxisRenderer* but this class cant be overloaded (?)

Is there a way to control the positioning of the x-axis labels without changing the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own Question:

1. Add the Date format as well as the scaling constants:

```
    private static final long MS_PER_XSCALE = 1000 * 60; // scale to minute resolution
    private static final long XSCALE_ONE_DAY = 60 * 24; // one day

    private final SimpleDateFormat xAxisDataFormat_DD_MMM_H = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MMM'_'H'h'", Locale.ENGLISH);
    private final SimpleDateFormat xAxisDataFormat_DD_MMM = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MMM", Locale.ENGLISH);
    private static final long TIMEOFFSET = TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset();
```

2. Set a customized Date Axis Renderer as well as the Date Formatter in onCreate() of the Activity:

```
        chart.setXAxisRenderer(new DateXAxisRenderer(chart.getViewPortHandler(), chart.getXAxis(), chart.getTransformer(null)));
        chart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
                if ((int) value / XSCALE_ONE_DAY * XSCALE_ONE_DAY == value)
                    return xAxisDataFormat_DD_MMM.format(new Date((long) value * MS_PER_XSCALE - TIMEOFFSET));
                else
                    return xAxisDataFormat_DD_MMM_H.format(new Date((long) value  * MS_PER_XSCALE - TIMEOFFSET));
            }
        });
```

3. Implement the Date Axis Renderer as follows:

```
 class DateXAxisRenderer extends XAxisRenderer {
        public DateXAxisRenderer(ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler, XAxis xAxis, Transformer trans) {
            super(viewPortHandler, xAxis, trans);
        }

        @Override
        protected void computeAxisValues(float min, float max) {
            int day_fraction[] = {1,2,3,4,6,8,12,24};
            float interval=0;
            int labelCount=0;
            float xMin = min;
            float xMax = max;

            xMax -= xMax % XSCALE_ONE_DAY;
            xMin += XSCALE_ONE_DAY - (xMin % XSCALE_ONE_DAY);
            int days = (int) ((xMax - xMin) / XSCALE_ONE_DAY);
            float days_interval = days / 3;
            if (days_interval > 0) {
                interval = days_interval * XSCALE_ONE_DAY;
                labelCount = (int) ((xMax - xMin) / interval);
            }

            if (days_interval == 0 || labelCount<3) {
                int i = day_fraction.length-1;
                do {
                    xMax = max - max % (XSCALE_ONE_DAY / day_fraction[i]);
                    xMin = min + (XSCALE_ONE_DAY / day_fraction[i] - (min % (XSCALE_ONE_DAY / day_fraction[i])));
                    labelCount = (int) ((xMax - xMin) / (XSCALE_ONE_DAY / day_fraction[i]));
                } while (labelCount > 4 && i-- > 0);
                interval = (xMax - xMin) / labelCount;
            }

            if (labelCount == 0 /*|| range <= 0 || Double.isInfinite(range)*/) {
                mAxis.mEntries = new float[]{};
                mAxis.mCenteredEntries = new float[]{};
                mAxis.mEntryCount = 0;
                return;
            }

            labelCount++;   // add last label
            //Timber.i("corrected min:" + xMin + ", max:" + xMax + ", interval:" + interval + ", labelcount:" + labelCount);

            mAxis.mEntries = new float[labelCount];
            float v = xMin;
            for (int i = 0; i < labelCount; i++) {
                mAxis.mEntries[i] = v;
                Timber.i("Label " + i + " at:" + mAxis.mEntries[i] + " day:" + mAxis.mEntries[i] / XSCALE_ONE_DAY);
                v += interval;
            }

            //mAxis.setLabelCount(labelCount);
            //mAxis.setGranularityEnabled(false);
            mAxis.mEntryCount = labelCount;
        }
    }
```

That's it!

Remark: The range which is nicely presented isl days down to minutes but i you need years, months or seconds you have to adapt the formatter as well as the implemented computeAxisValues() the it accordingly.